# where is the right place to add a footer for my seatle.master

Tags: master-page, page-layout, css

I have two site collections ; Team site and a Community site inside shatepoint server 2013. Both site collections are using seatle.master. and now i want to add a footer which contain a simple text for all my site collection web pages, so where is the right place within the Seatle.master page to add the footer ?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the footer within the `div` with the class `s4-bodyContainer` at the end of the div before closing the tag.

Maybe this helps:

```
<footer class="foot s4-notdlg">
     <div class="footerlegal">
         <asp:hyperlink runat="server" ID="lblLegalFooter" Text="<%$Resources:Intranet, Master_Footer_Legal %>" Mode="PassThrough" NavigateUrl="<%$Resources:Intranet, Master_Footer_Legal_Link %>"/>
     </div>
     <SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaSiteLogoFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
         <SharePoint:SPLinkButton ID="lbLogoFooter" runat="server" CssClass="logoFooter s4-notdlg" NavigateUrl='<%$Resources:Intranet, Master_Logo_Url %>' ToolTip='<%$Resources:Intranet, Master_Logo_ToolTip %>' ImageUrl="/Style Library/img/modules/ccontainers/logoFooter.png" />
     </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
 </footer>
```

foot class is

```
.foot { width: 100%; float: left; position:relative; bottom:0; left:0; min-height: 55px; border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e4e4; background: url("../img/general/bgFooter2.png") repeat-x;}
```

footerLegal is

```
.footerlegal a{
width: 21em;
text-align:center;
color: white;
left:45%;
position:absolute;
top:40%;
```

}

Logofooter is

```
.logoFooter{float:right; margin: 15px 32px 0 0;}
.logoFooter{float:right; margin: 15px 15px 0px 0px;}
.logoFooter > img{height: 26px;}
```

Comment: adding the footer on this place will move it to the top of the page when doing a search. i attach a screen shot of what is happening.

Comment: But have you applied my styles? Those classes are only an example of my implementation that surely will be different from yours. you need to adjust with css that footer

Answer (score 1):

Right before the ending `<div>` tag for div with ID `s4-workspace`.

Comment: i added it there, but when i did a search the footer will be on moved to the right of the search result at the top of the page. as shown in my edit (i attach a picture). can yuo advice

Comment: You need to add some CSS to it in order to put it where you want it.

Comment: like what CSS ?, on the footer CSS, i just added the following #customFooter{
font:bold 14px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:center;color: #008CD2 !important;
 

}

Comment: Try adding this CSS to it `width:100%; clear:both;`